# css class doesn't impact

Tags: html, css, class

I made a HTML file and linked it to a CSS file.
I have 3 classes, 2 are working and 1 isn't (class "info" doesn't work) 
Can you please help me understand why?

The HTML:

```
<table class="menues">
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="carrousel">
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="info">
    <tr>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The css file linked to it:

```
.menues{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    color: aliceblue;
}
.carrousel{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center; 
    color: aqua;
}
.info{
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 50p;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: blueviolet;

}
```

Comment: What is not working about this? This shows fine to me too: https://jsfiddle.net/uo52m0wv/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the 'x' on 'margin-left: 50p;'. It should be 'margin-left: 50px;'